# How to show credential dialog on client machine when using WNetUseConnection?

Tags: c#, remote-access

I am developing an web application where I need to connect remote machine to access files on its shared drive. User needs to be authenticated before giving access to these files.
I am using WNetUseConnection to prompt credential dialog.

WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, "", "", CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT, null, null, null);

Issue with this that it is opening the dialog on the server where this application is hosted not on the client machine. Can you someone help me to open the dialog on client machine .

Thanks!!!

Sample code:

Network layer:

```
    Public static Connect(string remoteUnc, string username, string password, bool promptUser)
    {
        NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE
        {
            dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
            lpRemoteName = remoteUnc
        };

        int result;
        if (promptUser)
        {
            result = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, "", "", CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT, null, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            result = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);
        }

        if (result != NO_ERROR)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

somefunction {
                using (NetworkLayer netAccess = 
                         NetworkLayer.Connect(hostName,null,null,true))
                {
                    //some logic
                }
}

WEBAPI:

```
  [HttpGet]

    public IActionResult RetrieveServerDetails(string hostname)
    {
        try
        {
            some function(hostname);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }`enter code here`
    }
```

Then calling this from jquery.

Comment: what does it mean open dialog on server ? im not sure it make sense - you client is serving ui  and logically it make sense for client to have credential dlg

Comment: yes..that should be the case.. but when we hosted application on a server and via UI when client tries to make API call to access remote files then we found the credential dialog is opened on server where this application is hosted not on the client UI.

Comment: please post code so people can see or minimal repro for it - thus it will be easy to find solution

Comment: You don't open dialogs on the client machine through a web browser. You collect the username and password with a web form. Allowing a user to define SMB connections server side is a massive security vulnerability. It's possible this question is missing details but it is unanswerable in the current state.